# How can I convert a 150 digit integer (or 30 5 digit ones) in Java to efficient storage format in mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, blob

In a java program I have 1..30 5 digit integers that I would like to store efficiently in mysql. I receive the digits 5 at a time. The number of 5 digit integers is unknown until the time of the mysql call, but the maximum total would be a 150 digit integer. I know that each 5 digit integer will be between 00000..99999 which can be stored using 17 bits (2^17 = 131072). 17 bits times a maximum of 30 5 digit integers is 510 bits which can be represented by 64 bytes.

I figured I would use a datatype of VARBYTE(64) for the column in my table. I was wondering:

- Are my calculations right for the max number of bytes it would take to represent this 5..150 digit number
- What would be the most efficient way, in Java, to get the blob to be inserted into the table?

edit:
After writing the question out I have decided that I will try out building a BitSet in Java and build a byte array out of that. My overall goal is to do selection in mysql on these blobs.

Comment: consider varchar(50) and store it as a string.  Unless you are doing math in stored procedures there is no need to store it as an integer value.

Comment: One possibility I can think of would be to have an array of length 5 boolean arrays. Then I could convert this to a byte array and make the mysql call using the byte array as an output stream.

Comment: My goal is to do a fast integer comparison so I would like to cut down on the size of the thing I'm comparing.

Comment: If they're separate integers, wouldn't it make more sense to keep them in a separate one-to-many table?

Comment: So, you are storing integers, then you need to search for them? Do you need to search a count or just if a certain integer exists?

Comment: Just if the integer exists. They will be unique to the table.

Comment: @shmosel the table will grow rather quickly in that case and the join operation needed for the selection would take longer than the search on the single, longer integer.

Comment: max long in java is 18 digits.  everything above that requires BigDecimal or the like.  Let go of the fantasy of fast integer comparison of 50 digit integers.

Comment: The integer comparison will occur in mysql based on the VARBYTE() that represents the 150 digit integer. In java the integer will be represented by a string which will be converted to a byte array. The byte array will be fed to the mysql as a blob column. This should provide the fastest comparison so long as the overhead in java is worth it. I will benchmark a bunch of the methods and post back here later after I have a finished product.

Answer (score 0):

Store your integers as `VARCHAR(179)` (5 digits * 30 numbers + 29 separator chars). For example:

```
key            values
-------------  ----------------------
'some value'   '123,7777,839,9843'
```

You can update your table using the [`INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) statement

```
INSERT INTO tbl (`key`,`values`) VALUES ('some value', '555,345')
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `values` = CONCAT(`values`, ',', '555,345');
```

Then filter the rows using the [`FIND_IN_SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function. Like this

```
SELECT * 
 FROM tbl
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('123', `values`);
```

In Java, just keep your integers as an array if `int` and update your column with a simple string concatenation. Just cast your integer values to string.

If you want to optimize, just put indexes on the necessary columns and benchmark it.

Comment: I will try this for now - will accept answer when implemented. I am still curious to see the selection time comparison of the various methods listed in comments and answers to this question.

Comment: As I am selecting for the set as a whole I simply need to select based on values as a string. Also, I do not need a delimiter since the format is guaranteed and can be easily parsed. I will use this method for now then optimize and benchmark with other methods later.

Comment: It is not too clear what you are trying to accomplish, really. Because other than that, having a table with a potential of 100000 indexed rows if probably the fastest solution... unless your set of 30 integers, while being unique in that set, may repeat in other sets.

Comment: That wouldn't work because there could be on the factor of 10^417 different strings to store. I only want to insert strings that aren't already in the table, and if they are, I want the ID.

Comment: ah! so, this is like a lottery, then?